# Windows Server 2019 drive mounted to folder and shared can NOT create file

Tags: permissions

I am running Windows Server 2019 mounting a drive to a folder (disk management / add drive letter  / ...) 
Sharing the folder I can access the share and create folders in it but I cannot create files or move a file to it

I tried all sorts of permissions

share permission everyone FULL control
security permission everyone FULL control
I am the owner
turning inheritance off and giving full permission to everyone 
and still I can't create a file in there from another machine

EDIT

It seems that you can not share a drive in general even if I try to share it through the file and storage services / share.

I  don't have the option to share a drive.

It gives me the option and creates a FOLDER on the drive which is shared then 
so although I can share a complete drive by hand I seem to by unable to give permission to be able to create files on it.

I can create folders but not files

Comment: I use Windows Server 2019 too, and folder/file sharing is kind of broken, unless you add a full-fledged file server role to your OS and use Active Directory. Do you have remote access enabled with the proper attributes (demand password, AD accounts, etc...)? Your best chance is to start from scratch when that kind of thing happens: delete the folder entirely (save its content onto another medium if need be), create it anew, preferably after restarting the server (if you can), and designate all the users or groups who can edit the folder AND its content.

Comment: Additionally, you can also Take Ownership of the folder in question, but if you intend to open its editing properties to others, that's not a viable option.

Comment: its not a folder i want to share but a complete drive i think i hitting some conceptual wall here and it wont be possible i can read it and create folders but cant create files on the root level just folders

Comment: The drive is physically on the premises or in a remote location? Sometimes, the mere fact that it's on a different subnet may cause that kind of issue, if said subnet obeys to different rules in terms of sharing drives, folders and files, for whatever reason.

Comment: server 10.1.1.5 <-> client 10.1.1.100 client is part of the domain and 10.1.1.5 is the DC
other shares works just fine eg. folders

Comment: Maybe there's a GPO in place that allows you to create new folders in this drive, but those folders are read-only?

Comment: lets say: drive D: share the DRIVE \\NAS\MyD\ ... i can create folders in this network location and whit hin the new folder create folders and files like \\NAS\MyD\NewFolder\SomeFile.txt but i can NOT create a file like \\NAS\MyD\SomeFile.txt

Comment: So you can create files within folders on this drive, but not at the root of the drive itself. What's the file system you used when you first installed that NAS? For example, I know that some Synology NASes only allow ext4 as their file system, and only a root user can create files right after the mounting point. Have you tried to format this drive in another file system, say FAT32 or NTFS (not exFAT, which has other limitations you don't want to face on a NAS right now)? (if that's even possible, that is)